# Wordpress pages with numbers in url

Tags: wordpress

I've found strange problem in my blog. Google index one page with several URLs:
example:

```
Main page:
http://www.example.com/2011/05/11/title/

Google add this too:
http://www.example.com/2011/05/11/title/1/
http://www.example.com/2011/05/11/title/2/
http://www.example.com/2011/05/11/title/3/
etc.
```

It is same pages. When I open source code of  http://www.example.com/2011/05/11/title/1/ page I see same url in canonical header (with /1/)!

I've tried to disabled all plugins, but I see pages with numbers /1/ still and I see this url in canonical tag. Looks like it is no plugin problem.

I can use any number but not letters: example /1a/ - 404

Why it is happen? How to fix it? How to use original url in canonical header?

Comment: Looks like this problem exists in all wrdpress sites. You can add /3/ (or another number) to page URL and you will see /3/ in canonical header in page source code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change permalink from admin under setting.

Comment: Now permalinks looks like this "/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/" I've tried to change it to "/%year%/%postname%/", but I still can open this page "/%year%/%postname%/3/" and will see "/%year%/%postname%/3/" in canonical url line.

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp dashboard then locate and click "**settings > permalinks**" then choose other format .

Comment: Now permalinks looks like this "/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/" I've tried to change it to "/%year%/%postname%/", but I still can open this page "/%year%/%postname%/3/" and will see "/%year%/%postname%/3/" in canonical url line.

Comment: try to set the permalink to plain

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress answers these URLs with a 301 redirect to the same URL without the /1/ appendix. That creates a problem, because WP does not respond with 404.

To have real 404 pages for these types of URLs you have to modify a core feature called "404 guessing" that is built into wordpress for over a decade.

This Blogpost describes the solution https://scottnelle.com/642/prevent-wordpress-guessing-users-hit-404-error/

Just put

```
function stop_404_guessing( $url ) {
 return ( is_404() ) ? false : $url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'stop_404_guessing' );
```

into your functions.php and you're good to go.